# Extracting the first element from strsplit, applied across each row element in data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table, strsplit

I have the following dataset:

```
library(data.table)

x <- data.table(a = c(1:3, 1), b = c('12 13', '14 15', '16 17', '18 19'))
> x
   a     b
1: 1 12 13
2: 2 14 15
3: 3 16 17
4: 1 18 19
```

and I would like to get a new dataset which has

```
> x
   a  b     c
1: 1 12 13 12
2: 2 14 15 14
3: 3 16 17 16
4: 1 18 19 19
```

so that it takes the first element of column `b`'s elements. I tried to do

```
x[,c:=unlist(strsplit(b, " "))[[1]][1]]
```

but it doesn't work. Is there a way to apply such a thing in `data.table`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `stringr::str_split_i` to take the first element of each split string:

```r
library(stringr)
x[, c := str_split_i(b, " ", 1)]
x
   a     b  c
1: 1 12 13 12
2: 2 14 15 14
3: 3 16 17 16
4: 1 18 19 18
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `tstrsplit` from `data.table`:

```
x[,c := tstrsplit(b," ")[1]]
x
   a     b  c
1: 1 12 13 12
2: 2 14 15 14
3: 3 16 17 16
4: 1 18 19 18



x[, c := readr::parse_number(b)]
x 
   a     b  c
1: 1 12 13 12
2: 2 14 15 14
3: 3 16 17 16
4: 1 18 19 18
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `sapply()` along with `strsplit()` and retain the first element from each vector in the list.

```r
x$c <- sapply(strsplit(x$b, " "), `[[`, 1)
x

   a     b  c
1: 1 12 13 12
2: 2 14 15 14
3: 3 16 17 16
4: 1 18 19 18
```

Comment: Can I ask what `[[` does? Thanks!

Comment: It is a list accessor, which is accessing the first element of the list.

Comment: ... and because it's a special operator (in that it is not used as a "normal" function as in `func(a,b,2)`) and contains characters R doesn't normally like in object/function names (some others: `-`, leading-with-number, `<`), it must be enclosed in backticks `\`[[\``. There